# Swift Socket Sever disconnected while moving to one view controller to other

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, tcp

I am trying to implement swift socket in my application. I am pretty new to socket programming. I have used

https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket

for socket connection. I had create NSObject class for Server Connection.

I want Server connected through out my whole application, But Server is disconnected while I'm moving into another ViewController.

```
class SocketGLobal : NSObject
{

func Connect()
    {
    let client = TCPClient(address: "www.apple.com", port: 80)
    switch client.connect(timeout: 1) {
      case .success:
        switch client.send(string: "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n" ) {
          case .success:
            guard let data = client.read(1024*10) else { return }

            if let response = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) {
              print(response)
            }
          case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem. So I created the custom ViewController and used *GCDAsyncUdpSocket* for socket connection. In your pod file add `pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'` to use *GCDAsyncUdpSocket*.  Here is the code snippet for custom ViewController.

```
import CocoaAsyncSocket
class CustomViewController: UIViewController, GCDAsyncUdpSocketDelegate {
    //MARK: VARIABLE DECLARATION **********
    var _udpSocket: GCDAsyncUdpSocket?
    var udpSocket: GCDAsyncUdpSocket? {
        get {
            if _udpSocket == nil {
                let port = 80
                let sock = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
                do {
                    sock.setIPv6Enabled(false)
                    //                    sock?.setIPv4Enabled(true)
                    //                    sock?.setPreferIPv4()
                    try sock.enableBroadcast(true)
                    try sock.bind(toPort: UInt16(port))
                    try sock.beginReceiving()

                } catch let err as NSError {
                    print(">>> Error while initializing socket: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                    sock.close()
                    return nil
                }
                _udpSocket = sock
            }
            return _udpSocket
        }
        set {
            _udpSocket?.close()
            _udpSocket = newValue
        }
    }

    //MARK: UDP SERVICES *********
    //Start UDP Receiver
    func startUDPService(){
        guard udpSocket != nil else {
            return
        }
    }

    //Stop UDP Receiver
    func closeUDPService(){
        if udpSocket != nil {                
            udpSocket?.close()
            udpSocket = nil                
        }
    }

    //MARK: HANDLING OF RECEIVED DATA **********
    func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceive data: Data, fromAddress address: Data, withFilterContext filterContext: Any?) {

        var hostPtr : NSString? = nil
        GCDAsyncUdpSocket.getHost(&hostPtr, port: &send_port, fromAddress: address)
        var receivedText = ""
        if let stringData = String(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            receivedText = stringData
        }
        print("Data received: \(String(describing: hostPtr)), \(receivedText)")
    }
}
```

In your each ViewController implement as follows:

```
import UIKit
class YourViewController: CustomViewController {

     //MARK: LIFE CYCLE METHODS **********
     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

          //MARK: START UDP SERVICE
          self.startUDPService()

     }

     override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
         //MARK: STOP UDP SERVICE
         self.closeUDPService()
     }
}
```

I hope this will help you.